# In Google Sheets, Find Ratio Between Cells in Two Columns, but First Number in Ratio Is Always Constant

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'd like to use a single header formula to find the ratio between the cells in two columns. (Columns A and B in this example.) I've found plenty of fairly easy solutions for the basic premise.

However, this next part is making it much trickier... I'd like to keep the first number in the ratio constant for an easier base of comparison, where only the second number changes (rounded up to a maximum of 3 decimal places). Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Here's the basic desired result...

| No. A | No. B | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | 20 | 3:1 |
| 1 | 0.66 | 3:1.98 |
| 90 | 50 | 3:1.667 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this formula in your Ratio column:

```
=CONCAT("3:",ROUND(B2/A2*3,3))
```

Comment: Oops, yes 60:20 should be 3:1. I fixed it, thank you!

Comment: It looks like your solution did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: How I adapted it... ={"Ratio";ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B<>"",CONCAT("3:",ROUND($B2:B/$A2:A*3,3)),))}